# TextInput going to middle of page

Tags: css, react-native

I have a `TextInput` in my app.js , but it stays in the middle of the page, But I want it to be on the top of the page, I mean just under the notification bar, Please how can I do this

```
 <View style={BackStyles.container}>
            <TextInput
                underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}  style={BackStyles.textBox}
            /></View>

const BackStyles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E2E2E2',
    marginTop: 20,
},
textBox: {
    height: 36,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    flexGrow: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#48BBEC',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `alignItems: 'center'` with `alignItems: 'flex-start'`.